# Call async task method from another class using wpf/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous

I'm trying to call an async Task method, from another class. The method is place within a service I have created.

**Service:**

```
public class GetRoomsService
{
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Room>> SearchForAvailableRooms(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Room> data = new ObservableCollection<Room>();
        return data; 
    }
}
```

In my wpf viewModel where I need to make the call, I have done it like:

```
// Start a search with default values from searchModel
RoomsList = _getRoomsService.SearchForAvailableRooms(searchModel.From, searchModel.To);
```

Where _getRoomsService in an instants of the service class.
Now I need to call it when it's set to async Task

Have tried with:

```
RoomsList = Task.Run<ICollection<Room>>(() => { return _getRoomsService.SearchForAvailableRooms(Search.To, Search.From); }).Result;
```

This does not work, and gives me an "Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type" error.

Hope someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If its not a duplicate (*ie. you are calling from a method also marked as async*) then its just a matter of doing `var roomlist = await _getRoomsService.SearchForAvailableRooms(Search.To, Search.From);`. Also its good practice to append `Async` to the name of your methods that are marked with the keyword `async`. So your method name would now be `SearchForAvailableRoomsAsync`

Comment: Have tried with await.. but it give me an "await can only be used within an async method" but it is async? or am I missing something?

Comment: It would help if you posted your method signature that you are wanting to call this from.

Comment: Found a way to solve this with "var result = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();"